# In Symphony CMS, how do I call an image into 'get-article.xsl'?

Tags: image, xslt, content-management-system

In my 'get-article.xsl', how do I call an image? I added a field in the article editor page to include a file upload, which uploads the image file to workspace/uploads. The code that I am trying to use to call the image is this, but I am not sure if it is correct.

```
<xsl:call-template name="article-images/entry">
<xsl:with-param name="entry-id" select="@id"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

I have not changed anything in the default 'get-images.xsl', as shown below.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template name="get-images">
    <xsl:param name="entry-id"/>
    <xsl:if test="/data/article-images/entry[article/item/@id = $entry-id]">
        <div class="article-images">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/article-images/entry[article/item/@id = $entry-id]"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="article-images/entry">
    <a href="{$workspace}/uploads/{image/filename}">
        <xsl:if test="position() mod 4 = 0">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">last-column</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <img title="{description}">
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:value-of select="$root"/>
                <xsl:text>/image/2/133/88/2/uploads/</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="image/filename"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </img>
    </a>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume there's you already have this Article Images DS and get-images.xsl (Utilities). If so, then you must add this Article Images DS in your Article "PAGE".

Once you added the Article Images. Check your get-article.xsl utilities if there is this kind of code:

```
<xsl:call-template name="get-images">
    <xsl:with-param name="entry-id" select="@id"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

If you can see it there. Go to your admin panel and add article or edit an existing one.

On the edit or create article page (where you can see text fields and areas). There's a button "Show Associates" at the upper right. Click that button, and another field where you can add images will appear. Just upload an image and it will automatically added in your article.